# Como saber si mi BD soporta transacciones? MYSQL- XAMPP

Tags: php, sql

Estoy realizando una transacccion pero aunque este mal una sentencia esta la ignora y ejecuta la siguente, lo cual esta mal ya que eso no es una transaccion, aqui les comparto el codigo:

```
public static function finishpackage($room, $finish_date) {
    $connection = self::connect();
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    
    try {

        $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
        (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet, start_date) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets, 
        start_date FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
        $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
        
        $query = $connection->prepare("UPDATE `finished_products` SET `finish_date`=:finish_date WHERE `room`=:room");
        $query->execute(["finish_date"=>$finish_date, "room"=>$room]);
        
        $query = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
        $result = $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
       
        $connection->commit();
        
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        $connection->rollBack();
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

me han preguntado cual es mi motor de BD, si INNODB O MyISAM, pero no se en donde ver eso, en tal caso si fuera uno de los dos, como haria? gracias :)

Comment: Debes validar primero si tu consulta es correcta, en caso de que no sea así, el programa se detiene. en tu try, puedes agregar un `if($query = = true){}` donde si, tu consulta es correcta que ejecute la query, en caso de que no sea correcta, que imprima un error o un mensaje.

Comment: en donde agrego ese if? debajo de cada sentencia?, pero que sentido tiene entonces usar la transaccion si esta no evalua por si mismo

Comment: Plus, échale un vistazo a [este link](https://thisinterestsme.com/php-pdo-transaction-example/), luego, si quieres saber el tipo de motor que usa una tabla en particular ejecuta lo siguiente: SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'producto'.

Comment: @r4ziel, vi y mi DB usa INNODB, tambien le agregue el PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, pero si hago esto me da error con mis consultas axios en vuejs, no me trae los datos que pido mediante peticiones get y post, por lo que o lo pongo en true o no lo declaro

Comment: @r4ziel, la transaccion como que medio funciona y a la vez no, porque todo depende de la primera consulta, si la primera consulta funciona las otras tambien (obvio) pero si la segunda consulta esta mal escrita y no funciona, esta ejecuta igual la primera consulta y no hace rollBack, sabras por que?

Comment: Es super curioso, a ver si investigando sacamos algo. ¿Puedes poner un enlace a un dump actual de la base de datos si no es privada?

Comment: ya lo resolvi @r4ziel, de tanta rabia de no veia a veces que tenia la setencia beginTrasaction dos veces y que los resultados de la base de datos se encontraban en las hojas siguientes

Comment: muy curioso xDDD